# How to add another navigation for mobile screen in responsive layout

Tags: wordpress, layout, navigation, responsive-design

I am working on wordpress theme design with responsive layout. Responsive layout is arranged using css3 media quires.Currently this theme navigation depends on Horizontal superfish navigation for large screen sizes. I want to change my navigation to vertical using superfish or accordian. How can I change  my navigation for mobile screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really depends on how the output code for your menu is structured to make it responsive. However, here are a couple ideas that may help. Sometimes you can hide the menu all together on mobile and have another version show up. This is tricky because hiding items in the DOM still output the HTML onto the mobile browser which increases the load time, but sometimes it is the best fix depending on usability.

Here is a quick snippet that outputs the scroll select on a mobile device like iPhone

```
<select class="iphone-menu" ONCHANGE="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option value="" selected="selected">Main Menu</option> 
<option value="/">Home</option> 
<option value="/portfolio">Portfolio</option> 
<option value="/services">Services</option> 
<option value="/knowledge">Knowledge</option> 
<option value="/blog">Blog</option> 
<option value="/about">About</option> 
<option value="/contact">Contact</option> 
</select>
```

I think for what you are wanting though you need are looking for something like this:
http://wpmegamenu.com/

I normally don't recommend plugins but this menu does collapse very well, and how you are wanting. Maybe this could be a good reference point. They make the list items 100% width at a certain point and then style the drop downs differently.

It doesn't do an accordion but it does do the drop downs. To do an accordion you would have to activate a script on window resize with javascript so it only functioned as an accordion on mobile and turned off on desktops and tablets. I am by no means an expert at js so maybe someone else can direct you better but a basic resize function would be something like this:

```
    function checkWidth(init)
{
    /*If browser resized, check width again */
    if ($(window).width() < 979 ) {

        // accordion script here

    }
    else {
        if (init == false) {

            // deactivate script here

        }
    }
}

// this function returns the width of the browser window
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkWidth(true);

    $(window).resize(function() {
        checkWidth(false);
    });
});
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction. I have implemented different menus on responsive sites using these different methods and they have worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! This is the main idea behind switching navigation style. On window re-size style is changing, so I can put any style on window re-size.